# Save/Load Data Android device , Unity , C#

Tags: c#, android, save, unity-game-engine

Hey i want to make a Android Game now my step was Save/Load Data. Now i test it on my PC all goes perfect, The Game creates the Saves folder and saves my bool. Then i put the Apk on my Android device. When the game has to save the bool it stands still. (not a freeze frame but it dont go on).

Here the Code i used to save Data:

Save(It will start the method if you win a level): public void SaveData()

```
 {
     bool nextlevel = true;

     if (!Directory.Exists("Saves"))
         Directory.CreateDirectory("Saves");

     BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
     FileStream saveFile = File.Create("Saves/save.level." + nextScence);

     formatter.Serialize(saveFile, nextlevel);
     saveFile.Close();
 }
```

Load(I need load in my Level screen to check if the player has played the level):

```
             try
             {
                 BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                 FileStream saveFile = File.Open("Saves/save.level." + level, FileMode.Open);

                 nextlevel = (bool)formatter.Deserialize(saveFile);

                 saveFile.Close();
             }
             catch (FileNotFoundException e)
             {
                 nextlevel = false;
             }
```

I hope you can Help me ,thanks for help

I only know this method to Save data if you now a better one and if its go on android to please tell it to me !

Comment: never use "BinaryFormatter" for any reason ever.  Do what Programmer explains below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are **only** checking if player has **played** a level. Don't make this complicated. Use **Unity** **built** in class PlayerPrefs to check if player has **played** the level.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

When player has played level 1, you can create a key called "hasPlayedLevel1" and write **1** to it like below:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("hasPlayedLevel1", 1); //1 for yes, 0 for no
```

Later on in the game or when player **closes** and **re-opens** the game, you can check if the player has **played** the level.

```
    bool hasplayedLevel = false;
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("hasPlayedLevel1") == 1)
    {
        hasplayedLevel = true;
    }
    else
    {
        hasplayedLevel = false;
    }

    if (hasplayedLevel)
    {
        //Players has played this level
    }
    else
    {
        //Players has NOT played this level
    }
```

You can again mark that the player has **NOT** played the level by writing **0** to `hasPlayedLevel1`.

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("hasPlayedLevel1", 0);
```

Comment: Okay thanks i will test it

Comment: Yes its perfect and simple thx !